# One-line rendering of a multi-line DBMemo in a TDBCtrlGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I am using a TDBCtrlGrid with a multi-line DBMemo in Delphi 10.3. When the panel is in focus, the behavior is normal. In unfocused panels, the text becomes a single line.

How do I make all panels look the same?

[image]

The value of the fields for different records is equal. First records in focus.

Comment: A focused cell can invoke an editor which often shows contents differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After analyzing the example code of @MartynA

My problem was with the data type of field.

Data type `TStringField` is displayed on one line.
Data type `TMemoField` is displayed as multi-line.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code os a minimal test project which includes a TClientDataSet. TDataSource, TDBGrid and
TDBCtrlGrid.  It is intended to be completely self-contained in that all the
relevant component properties and the record data are set in code in the `FormCreate` event. It contains
a compiler define to control whether the field displayed in the TDBMemo is a
TStringField or a TMemoField.

If I compile and run the project, I get this display, whether the compiler define is active or not.

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, the 3 instances of the DBMemo image all correctly display 4 lines
of data, as expected.  Obviously, this does not reproduce the behaviour you illstrated.  Perhaps
by comparing this with your project, you may be able to identify why yours behaves differently.
Perhaps it is to do with the contents of the DBMemo strings or the font you are using?

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
  DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
  DBNavigator1: TDBNavigator;
  DataSource1: TDataSource;
  DBCtrlGrid1: TDBCtrlGrid;
  DBMemo1: TDBMemo;
  ClientDataSet1: TClientDataSet;
[...]
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  AField : TField;
  MemoValue : String;
  i : Integer;
begin
  AField := TIntegerField.Create(ClientDataSet1);
  AField.FieldName := 'Field1';
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;

{.$define UseStringField}
{$ifdef  UseStringField}
  AField := TStringField.Create(ClientDataSet1);
  AField.FieldName := 'Field2';
  AField.Size := 1024;
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
{$else}
  AField := TMemoField.Create(ClientDataSet1);
  AField.FieldName := 'Field2';
  AField.DataSet := ClientDataSet1;
{$endif}

  ClientDataSet1.IndexFieldNames := 'Field1';
  ClientDataSet1.CreateDataSet;
  ClientDataSet1.Open;

  DBMemo1.Width := 150;
  DbCtrlGrid1.RowCount := 1;
  DbCtrlGrid1.ColCount := 3;
  DbCtrlGrid1.PanelWidth := DBMemo1.Width + 20;
  DBMemo1.Left := 10;
  DbCtrlGrid1.Width := 3 * DbCtrlGrid1.PanelWidth;

  for i := 1 to 3 do begin
    MemoValue := 'record: %d' + sLineBreak + 'line2' + sLineBreak + 'line3' + sLineBreak + 'line4' + SLineBreak;
    MemoValue := Format(MemoValue, [i]);
    ClientDataSet1.InsertRecord([i, MemoValue]);
  end;
  ClientDataSet1.First;
end;
```

Comment: The behavior will be produced if in your example set `{$ define UseStringField}`

Comment: Well, I said in my answer "I get this display, whether the compiler define is active or not."  What I meant was that the display I get is identical when `UseStringField` is defined and when it is not.